# Using boost iterator adaptor/facade on top of custom iterator

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a custom collection `Collection`. a custom iterator `Iter` over it returning `Obj*`, and an object wrapper `Wrapper`:

```
Collection c;
// Collection initialization skipped here
Iter it = c.getIter();
while (Obj* obj = it++) {
    Wrapper w(obj);
    w.doSomething();
}
```

I want to create an STL-like iterator (both `iterator` and `const_iterator` with no code duplication) to have my code look like:

```
for (Collection::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
    it->doSomething();
}
```

and

```
for (Collection::const_iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
    it->querySomething();
}
```

How can I use boost iterator adaptor/facade to achieve this?

I believe I should use `boost::iterator_facade`:

```
 ... : public boost::iterator_facade<Derived, Value, CategoryOrTraversal, Reference>
```

My first question is what should `Value` and `Reference` type parameters be. `Reference` is obviously `Wrapper`, because it is the result of the iterator dereference, but what is `Value`?

Comment: Boost's libraries are definitely the way to go here. Have you read [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#iterator-facade-requirements)?  Do you have a partial implementation?  What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I am working on it currently.Wanted to find an example that could help me. I went through the documentation, but it is not that straightforward.

Comment: Can you include a bit more about what you did so far in the question? Right now, it's rather close to a "please write the code for me" post. Better than most from that category, but still rather close to it. Or at least explain what concrete problems you have.